# 'is' functions and 'get_query_var' not working

Tags: functions, ajax, template-tags

Why does `is` functions not work inside an Ajax function? Except for `is_user_logged_in`?

I also tried using `get_query_var` and it did not work.

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.post-modal').live('click', function(e) {       

    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('post-id');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: mysite.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action' : 'post_modal_content',
            'post_id' : post_id             
        },                      
        success: function(response) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            jQuery('#post-modal .content').html(json.html);             
        }                                   
    });     
});
```

PHP:

```
function post_modal_content() {

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];   

    if (is_author()) {
        set_query_var('post_id', $post_id);
        ob_start();
        get_template_part('content-post-modal');
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();  

        $response = array('html' => $html);
        echo json_encode( $response );
        exit;
    }   
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_modal_content', 'post_modal_content' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_modal_content', 'post_modal_content' );
```

If I am on the author page it does not work, but if I take the check everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send your AJAX request to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` (which is very good), so it's not a typical WP request.

During such request, request is not parsed, no global WP_Query is created, and so on.

[`is_author`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) is a [Conditional Tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), which checks if an Author archive page is being displayed. So, by design, it will return false during AJAX request, because AJAX request is not displaying author archive page...

On the other hand, `is_user_logged_in()` works, because user is still logged in during AJAX request (it's the same session).

PS. It's the same with `get_query_var` - no query is parsed or executed, so there are no query variables available...

Comment: Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: @Alex no. AJAX request is different request, so you don't have access to variables from another request... Of course you can add any variables to your AJAX call (as you're already passing post_id).